# R problems using rpart with 4000 records and 13 attributes

Tags: r, rpart

I have attempted to email the author of this package without success,
just wondering if anybody else has experienced this.

I am having an using `rpart` on 4000 rows of data with 13 attributes.
I can run the same test on 300 rows of the same data with no issue.
When I run on 4000 rows, Rgui.exe runs consistently at 50% CPU and the
UI hangs; it will stay like this for at least 4-5hours if I let it
run, and never exit or become responsive.

here is the code I am using both on the 300 and 4000 size subset:

```
train <- read.csv("input.csv", header=T)
y <- train[, 18]
x <- train[, 3:17]
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(y ~ ., x)
```

Is this a known limitation of `rpart`, am I doing something wrong?
potential workarounds?

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're using `R` to begin with... whoo. ;-)

Comment: It's basically impossible to tell without `input.csv`.

Comment: What is the package, rpart or mvpart? Are your packages up to date? Have you tried another method? e.g. rpart(y~.,x,method="anova") ?
I just tried partitioning a dataset of 165744 observations and 7 variables and it took 58.78 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here was data prep error.

a header was re-written far down in the middle of the data set.

Answer (score 2):

Can you reproduce the error message when you feed rpart random data of similar dimensions, rather than your real data (from input.csv)? If not, it's probably a problem with your data (formatting perhaps?). After importing your data using read.csv, check the data for format issues by looking at the output from 
str(train).

```
#How to do an equivalent rpart fit one some random data of equivalent dimension
dats<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4000*14), nrow=4000))

y<-dats[,1]
x<-dats[,-1]
library(rpart)
system.time(fit<-rpart(y~.,x))
```